# What is the correct syntax for creating an object from an implemented class

Tags: java

Since I'm taking Java and C++ at the same time, I sometimes confuse my syntax. My problem is simple. I need to create a class (IBuyer) that is implemented by other classes. I'm trying to write a function that will return an object of IBuyer in my Main but it says its abstract and cannot be instantiated. I add abstract to the definition of the other classes but it still doesn't like it. What does it want?

IBuyer class:

```
public interface IBuyer {    
    String GetName();
    String GetPassword();
    void SetName(String sName);
    void SetPassword(String sPass);    
} //end interface IBuyer
```

Another class named Standard:

```
public abstract class Standard implements IBuyer {    
    private String userSName;
    private String userSPass;
    private String userSType;

.
.
.
}
```

My Main.java file:

```
public IBuyer GetUser (String name, String password) {

    IBuyer newBuyer = new IBuyer(name, password);

    return newBuyer;
};

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String uName;
    String uPass;
```

.
.
.

}

This is what it doesn't like that I need syntax help with:

```
IBuyer newBuyer = new IBuyer(name, password);
```

Thank you

Comment: You can only instantiate a concrete class, not an abstract one.

Comment: You can't instantiate interfaces like that at all either.

Comment: What do you think that line does?

Comment: "I add abstract to the definition of the other classes but it still doesn't like it." Please protect your own sanity and don't add code you don't understand to fix errors you don't understand. You'll wind up in a worse mess than before.

Comment: You also need to learn what `abstract` means.

Comment: I'd suggest to read up on the language basics before asking questions, for example Java Tutorial: [Classes and Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html) and [Interfaces and Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

As the error is trying to tell you, you cannot create an instance of an interface or abstract class.

Instead, you need to create an instance of the concrete class that inherits the interface (`Standard`)

Comment: Upvoted, but `Standard` is currently `abstract` in there, not concrete.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the naming convention, `IBuyer` is an interface of some sort, and you can't instantiate interfaces with the `new` keyword.  They have no implementation.

What you have to do is derive from the interface, and instantiate the derived class.

now you've done that to an extent, but you've made it abstract

```
public abstract class Standard implements IBuyer {
```

the keyword `abstract` means that the class itself **can't** be instanciated, instead, it should be derived from.

So, if you intended to instantiate `Standard`s, than you should get rid of the `abstract` keyword. and use

```
IBuyer newBuyer = new Standard(name, password);
```

---

you could alternatively derive yet another class from Standard such as

```
public class MyClass extends Standard{
```

and then use

```
IBuyer newBuyer = new MyClass(name, password);
```

Comment: That would still need a constructor.

Comment: Thank you Sam, that makes sense. It doesn't help that the instructions are vague, and the book explains it as if your a novice programming in java, which I am not, but I think I got it.